# Failed audit: fail to see actually abuse/spam/offensive content

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

Sorry for asking this in a new question, but similar posts asking similar question entailed generally obvious bad content, like link-only or off-topic posts.

Can issues like this be properly resolved (by some short guidance/explanation) in another way (e.g. mod contact, chat)?

I [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33573138) on an answer that allegedly is *“abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable”*, and thus has been deleted because it was *“flagged as spam or offensive content”*.

Screenshot:

[image]

The way I saw it the first time, and on every re-evaluation since, it’s on-topic, in response to the OP, a sincere attempt to respond, contains no offensive speech (neither in the weblinks), and was even suggested to be an accepted answer by the questioner.

Am I wrong, or is it?

Comment: Who are you quoting in your initial paragraphs here?

Comment: @Larnu: Myself, in another tone of thought, for another, meta question related to the core issue – should I better change it to a horizontal rule below it?

Comment: So you said the above in another post? It seems odd to quote yourself from another (presumably related) post and not link to that post then. What is the related post?

Comment: Looking at that answer, the user who posted it has been deleted. I suspect that the user was a spam account. Probably they were linked to the tutorial site that was linked in that post in many of their answers.

Comment: The first link in the last line is spam. They posted another 5 answers with links to the same site

Comment: Yeah, I just did a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1693671?UserId=20411039) and see that it's linked in all their posts (SEDE hasn't been updated yet, as they were only deleted yesterday, hence why I could query this).

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine, how is it spam? It contains an on-topic code tutorial. If it’s fitting the particular question, how does posting it elsewhere count? Also, if a user is deleted, but the answer is valid, does it becomes spam altogether?

Comment: When a user links to that website in *all* of their content, it then denotes a pattern, @dakab . Linking to documentation and related content can be helpful, but linking to the *same* tutorial site over and over suggests something else (note that linking to official documentation each time wouldn't be an issue; I've provided 100's, if not 1,000's, of links to Microsoft documentation over the years, for example).

Comment: Same goes for MDN and others, but I guess it’s nowhere specified what links wouldn’t be an issue. In a specific review task, it’s a bit hard to check whether they used the same links elsewhere and how often, isn’t it? And in this questionable case, if the provided code was obviously helpful, and all but one link was perfectly coherent, it’s not a particularly adequate fail, is it?

Comment: @Larnu how can one know that a user had posted a link over and over again? Especially when that user was deleted and probably the only availability of these posts is in such an audit (or 10k+ rep users).

Comment: Does this not cover the topic extremely well? https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: The real problem is that you're expected to do an unreasonable amount of work to detect spam.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk finding new spam takes a lot of work.  Once you do more than a glance at old spam it being from a deleted user should stand out like a giant red flag.  Audits are more about if you're paying attention than they are about actually training you to catch bad behavior.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight 'Audits are more about if you're paying attention than they are about actually training you to catch bad behavior.' Then it's still a bad audit. I agree that it is that way at SO, however that's still not a good audit system.

Comment: @MagnusO_O - In this case the author failed to identify a contribution that was clearly spam.  In this case the audit system worked, the author hopefully will use all available resources, to analyze if a contribution is spam. "how can one know that a user had posted a link over and over again?" - You can search for the URL.  Since it was already deleted, had the author opened up the question in another tab, they would have quickly realized the contribution had already been deleted. There are problems with the audit system but this isn't one of those examples.

Comment: @SecurityHound I can't see the audit (probably due to not enough rep), but from the explanations and comments of e.g. Larnu concerning having to check if that link was posted several times already it seems not to be an obvious one.

Comment: @SecurityHound 'had the author opened up the question in another tab, they would have quickly realized the contribution had already been deleted. ' that's my point, an audit system where that is required isn't a good audit system.

Comment: @MagnusO_O - Here is the thing, the review system suggested the content of the contribution was a problem, that is the point as a reviewer you use all resources at your disposal.  *You can't actually cheat on audits, so opening up the question, to determine if something is an audit isn't cheating.* There are bad audits that exist, but an audit on deleted spam, serves a purpose in my opinion.

Comment: @SecurityHound agree for a normal spam audit. This one seems to be special (again, I can't see it, just deriving that from the comments). And an audit that has another review result whether it's identified as an audit or not just trains identifying audits, not identifying bad contributions - and that's not a good audit system in my point of view.

Comment: @SecurityHound: You saying "it's clearly spam" does not make it so. Why should a reviewer need to open up the question/answer in another tab? For only one reason, and that is to detect if this is an audit. That's definitely not what a audit should be about. It should about the question/answer content.

Comment: Often there's something in a post or profile that points to a particular link by that user being spam. But sometimes there isn't - and past a certain point, it can be quite difficult to distinguish between a spam link and simply a link to a lesser-known site you've never seen before - especially if no other posts by that user referencing that site remain visible on their profile.

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't understand why auditors should be expected to do any more scrutiny on individual links than checking the URL to see if it points to hxxps://uselesswidgets.buynow.biz (redacted because apparently someone actually registered that domain!) or something. The **entire premise** of a review queue is to consider posts **one at a time, in isolation**, and judge them **on their content** rather than the user (since, after all: this is not a discussion forum; we downvote posts rather than users; closing and deleting questions is nothing personal; etc. etc. etc.)

Comment: This is a bad audit, plain and simple. Yes, it was spam. That was obvious to the mod who handled it originally and deleted it as such, but that's because they could see the additional context that the user had posted many other answers promoting the same site. There's no way that context would be available to you, as a reviewer, even if you thought to look. Sure, you could trivially pass these audits by opening them in a new tab, and while there's nothing wrong with that, that's not the expectation of the audit mechanism. That means this is a bad audit.

Comment: In this case, you're not review-banned, so there's nothing that needs to be done here. Compounding matters is that moderators don't currently have a way to manually remove a post from the pool of potential audits. This is causing issues for ChatGPT-flagged answers, too. I have asked a CM to find out what we can do, and, if there is nothing (all of the tricks we used to use have broken now with the last redesign of the review queues), to implement something. For now, since this is actually spam, I can re-delete as R/A to prevent it from being an audit.

Comment: A “thank you very much!” to each and every commentator, but particularly @​CodyGray @​KarlKnechtel @​MagnusO_O @​PresidentJamesK.Polk *(alphabetic)* … I’m a bit relieved and understand the specific reason as well as the broader issue of such cases.

Comment: This is definitely a bad audit. But fact of the matter remains that there is only one way to not ever be caught by bad audits; open every post in a separate tab so you can see what you see there matches what the review is showing you. It is the thing you have to do if you want to prevent this. The next terrible audit is already coming towards you as we speak; it might strike today, tomorrow or next week. Better get used to the idea of just making that standard procedure during reviewing or you will burn out eventually.

Comment: @Gimby And I feel that is a problem. If you need to spot an audit in order to correctly answer an audit, then the audit is missing its point. The audit is supposed to check if you are paying attention to the content you are reviewing (and if you decisions are sound) and not if you are able to spot audits...

Comment: @CharonX - In my experience while there are a handful of questions that shouldn't be considered a valid audit, the vast majority of audits, are to put it simply extremely easy to identify as an audit.  It only takes a moment of your time to determine the proper course of action. Of course the steps you take to determine what that action should be, are the same steps, you should take regardless if it's an audit.  Opening the review in another tab, isn't to identify if something is an audit, it's to get a complete picture to choose the correct review action.